# fetching data from two string array to two different layouts into a single listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout, android-arrayadapter

i have seen many answers and i changed my code accordingly. now i am stuck with my own problem.after running this adapter , i am getting one value from list1 and only two values from list2 where both have three values.the layouts are coming fine.i don't know what is causing it and i am also not that much familiar with arrayadapter. it will be a great help. thanks in advance.

```
public class AxisAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    private Context context;
    private final int view1 = 0;
    private final int view2 = 1;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> records,ArrayList<String> records1) {
        super(context, 0, records);
        this.context = context;
        list1=records;
        list2=records1;

    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == 0) ? view1 : view2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case view1: {
                final String item = list1.get(position);

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.abc_layout, parent, false);
                }
                final TextView list_Txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDef);
                Button list_But = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCall);

                list_Txt.setText(item.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", " "));


                list_But.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String number = item.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "");

                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }

                });
            }
            break;
            case view2: {
                final String item = list2.get(position);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.url_layout, parent, false);
                }
                final TextView list_Txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDetail);
                Button list_But = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnVisit);
                list_Txt.setText(item.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", " "));
                list_But.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String number = item.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "");
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("tel:12345"));
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;


        }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

in my activity class

```
public class AnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    AxisAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_axis);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if(getSupportActionBar()!= null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.axisList);
        String[] ussd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.axisCode);
        String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.axisLink);

        ArrayList<String> myData = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> myLinks = new ArrayList<String>();


        for(int i = 0; i<ussd.length;i++) {
            myData.add(ussd[i]);
        }

        for(int i =0;i<links.length;i++){
            myLinks.add(links[i]);

        }

        adapter = new AxisAdapter(this,myData,myLinks);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        //adapter= new AxisAdapter(this,myLinks);
        //list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            finish();


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and in my both layout class, there is one button and one text box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/textboxColor">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDef"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
            android:text="Call"
            android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

another one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/textboxColor">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnVisit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
            android:text="Visit"
            android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concern:

> i am getting one value from list1 and only two values from list2 where
>   both have three values

The problem you are facing lies in these places:

```
private final int view1 = 0;
private final int view2 = 1;
```

...

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == 0) ? view1 : view2;
}
```

And then you call getItemViewType method in the getView() method:

```
int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
```

The value of position ranges from 0 to the number of items in the list minus 1. So the getItemViewType() method always return 0 (view1) if position = 0, and return 1 (view2) if position = 1, 2, 3...

You then write:

```
    switch (viewType) {
                case view1: {
                    final String item = list1.get(position);

                 ...

                            }
                break;
            case view2: {
                final String item = list2.get(position);

                 ...

                        }
                break;
                    }
```

In the `case view1`, it is simply indicating the first item in your list with position = 0. There is only 1 item staying at position 0, so `final String item = list1.get(position);` is only called once, that is why it returns 1 value.

In the `case view2`, it is simply indicating the items at position 1, 2, 3... As you said there are 3 items in the list, the adapter will generate 3 items for the list view and `case view2` will be equal to position 1 and 2. So `final String item = list2.get(position);` is called twice, that is why it returns 2 values.

I dont know what your next step would be because I don't understand what you expect.

***Update:*** specific solution:

```
public class AxisAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList<String> list1;
    private ArrayList<String> list2;

    private Context context;

    public AxisAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> records,ArrayList<String> records1) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.context = context;
        list1=records;
        list2=records1;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list1.size() + list2.size();
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (position < list1.size()) {
            final String item = list1.get(position);
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.abc_layout, parent, false);

            final TextView list_Txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDef);
            Button list_But = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCall);

            list_Txt.setText(item.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", ""));


            list_But.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String number = item.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "");

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }

            });
        }

        else {

            final String item = list2.get(position - list1.size());
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.url_layout, parent, false);
            final TextView list_Txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDetail);
            Button list_But = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnVisit);
            list_Txt.setText(item.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", ""));
            list_But.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String number = item.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "");
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("tel:12345"));
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: then what should i change to iterate it for both the list one by one completely?  i tried a for loop inside my case statement till the size of my lists and set that value inside my item string. it doesnot worked. any detail you need i will give you.just help me out.

Comment: let me see your main layout, abc_layout, Activity class (and Fragment class if any). You can post them by editing your question

Comment: i posted it . look at it once.

Comment: in what order do you want to display the items in the list view? like the first 3 lines in list view will be occupied by List 1, the last 3 lines will be used for list 2?

Comment: yes ... first list will also follow one layout and the other will the other layout.

Comment: just copy and past the whole AxisAdapter i share in the answer

Comment: whats happening is, i am getting only list1's value and the value of position is only showing 0,1,2. why is that?

Comment: can u plz share screenshot of the mobile device and Logcat messages

Answer (score 0):

Try to send some string like in below case a string to determine the type, what you are actually trying to switch between, in my case it was monthly,yearly and so on, based on that string you can use different views or maybe show alternative layouts easily.

```
public class incomeadapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private List<Incomemodel> getdatas;
private int resource;
String incometype;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

public incomeadapter(Context context, int resource, List<Incomemodel> getdata, String type) {
    super(context, resource, getdata);
    this.context = context;
    getdatas = getdata;
    incometype = type;
    this.resource = resource;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView t1, t2;

    if (convertView == null) {

        if (incometype.equals("monthly")) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.incomemonthly_item, null);


            t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            t1.setText(getdatas.get(position).getMonths());
            t2.setText(getdatas.get(position).getIncome());

        }
        if (incometype.equals("yearly")) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.incomeyearly_item, null);


            t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            t1.setText(getdatas.get(position).getYear());
            t2.setText(getdatas.get(position).getIncome());

        }

    }


    return convertView;
}
}
```

**PS. Try using recyclerview with multiple viewholders, that will make it easy i guess**